# How to use object prop in Child component using Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a child component called Card.vue where I make a card based on the length of an object in the parent component. In the child component I would like to use the data inside the object send from the parent. I get the error message that 'legend' is not defined. How do I do solve this?

Parent component:

```
<alst-card v-for="(legend, index) in profile.legends.all" :key="index" v-bind="legend"></alst-card>
```

Child component:

```
<p class="card-text" style="min-width: 100px">{{ legend.data.kills.value }}</p>

export default {
  props: {
    legend: Object
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `v-bind:legend="legend"` instead of `v-bind="legend"`

The `legend` on the left is the `props` that the child component declared, the `legend` on the right is the `data`/property from the parent.

For example if your children declared:

```
export default {
  props: {
    givemelegend: Object
  }
}
```

Then in Parent.Vue, you would want: `v-bind:givemelegend="legend"`

Comment: The legend in the for loop is an object I'm trying to pass and according to the official documentation, in order to pass an object you have to v-bind="nameHere".
However it is not explained in the documentation how to catch the object in the child and that is where it goes wrong, I think.

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-an-Object

Comment: @JesseyFransen If you want to pass **the `legend` object**, you have to `v-bind:legend="legend"`, but if you want to pass **the properties of the `legend` object**, then `v-bind="legend"` will be what you want. *(From the link you give above)*. Your case might be the first one, but you had used the second syntax.

Comment: Use `v-bind` is like the *spread operator*. For example your `legend` is `{ name: 'Jessey', age: 25 }`, then `v-bind="legend"` is equivalent to `v-bind:name="legend.name" v-bind:age="legend.age"`. Apparently here your ChildComponent.Vue expects a `legend` Object as props, not `name` and `age`.